# Constant error when writing in files in create-react-app based project in WebStorm

Tags: ide, webstorm, create-react-app

I am constantly getting an error from babylon.js (which I'm not sure I'm even using?) in my "Run" terminal in WebStorm.

I get the following error:

```
cmd.exe /D /C call C:/Users/Jens/IdeaProjects/Vaskemaskine/WashingmachineFrontend/vaskemaskine-app/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/.bin/babylon.cmd --source-maps --out-file strings-compiled.js --presets es2015 C:\Users\Jens\IdeaProjects\Vaskemaskine\WashingmachineFrontend\vaskemaskine-app\src\strings.js
fs.js:549
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Jens\IdeaProjects\Vaskemaskine\WashingmachineFrontend\vaskemaskine-app\src\--source-maps'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jens\IdeaProjects\Vaskemaskine\WashingmachineFrontend\vaskemaskine-app\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\bin\babylon.js:13:15)
```

Occasionally I will also get an error in a popup in WebStorm:

```
Cannot save C:\Users\Jens\IdeaProjects\Vaskemaskine\WashingmachineFrontend\vaskemaskine-app\src\strings.js.
The file left unchanged.
Your changes were written to strings.js___jb_tmp___.
```

Not sure if that is related or not.

I tried googling around, but no one seems to be having the same problem as me. Anyone has a clue about what is going on? I haven't configured the scripts delivered with create-react-app, other than "ejecting" out.

Comment: `strings.js___jb_tmp___` -- go to `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings` and disabled `Use "safe write"...` option -- this will make IDE to save new file content into the same file directly instead of writing into temp file first and then renaming the file. Not sure if it will help with initial issue though... (they do not seem related)

Comment: looks as if you have set up a file watcher for babylon.cmd, and it has problems parsing the arguments you are passing to it. Check File | Settings | Tools | File Watchers - do you have any? as for the second issue, it may be caused by sharing violation - some application might be blocking the file you are trying to edit

Comment: I have no idea why Babylon was setup in my project to watch files, wasn't using it for anything. Removing it solved the problem. Thanks to both of you.